# Controllers not working for Mac Games

Tags: pc, controllers, macos

I am having a problem when playing games with a controller on my MacBook Pro OS X El Capitan. I tested an Xbox 360 controller after installing a third party software on github [360Controller](https://github.com/360Controller/360Controller/releases) and it worked fine, but when trying to play the game with a controller, it doesn't recognize it.

I tried it on Outlast, Darksiders 2, Batman Arkham City, but it doesn't work and is not even recognized on these games.

I read that these games supported Xbox 360 controllers, so I don't know what the problem is. When I tried an Xbox 360 controller on LIMBO, it worked fine just.

Also I tried a DualShock 4 controller, but it isn't recognized and did not work for these games.

Comment: I am on Yosemite OSX so i cant answer this definitively, but ive had a lot of luck using the cheap Afterglow wired xbox 360 controllers, using the same software you linked to. It usually is recognized by 3/4 games i try it with, but not always perfectly (bumpers and/or triggers wont map sometimes)

Comment: I am having the same issue but just to check: assuming you are playing these games on Steam, are you making sure they have controller support?

Comment: Yes. I am sure that these games have controller support but I didn't figure out why they are not working.it will be appreciated if some one help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the controller driver in Systems Preferences and open the Advanced Tab you will see a check box to "Enable Driver". Make sure that is on. Also at the bottom there is another check box for "Pretend to be an xbox 360 controller", also turn that on. Your games should now be able to sync with your controller.